# How do I open an array of files in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, simultaneous

In perl, I read in files from a directory, and I want to open them all simultaneously (but line by line) so that I can perform a function that uses all of their nth lines together (e.g. concatenation).

```
my $text = `ls | grep ".txt"`;
my @temps = split(/\n/,$text);
my @files;
for my $i (0..$#temps) {
  my $file;
  open($file,"<",$temps[$i]);
  push(@files,$file);
}
my $concat;
for my $i (0..$#files) {
  my @blah = <$files[$i]>;
  $concat.=$blah;
}
print $concat;
```

I just a bunch of errors, use of uninitialized value, and GLOB(..) errors. So how can I make this work?

Comment: **`Always`** put `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of a Perl program. Do that until you know exactly why you should do that.

Comment: "Do that until you know exactly why you should do that." And then keep doing it unless you have a very specific reason not to and know exactly what will happen because of it.

Answer (score 15):

A lot of issues. Starting with call to "ls | grep" :)

Let's start with some code:

First, let's get list of files:

```
my @files = glob( '*.txt' );
```

But it would be better to test if the given name relates to file or directory:

```
my @files = grep { -f } glob( '*.txt' );
```

Now, let's open these files to read them:

```
my @fhs = map { open my $fh, '<', $_; $fh } @files;
```

But, we need a way to handle errors - in my opinion the best way is to add:

```
use autodie;
```

At the beginning of script (and installation of autodie, if you don't have it yet). Alternatively you can:

```
use Fatal qw( open );
```

Now, that we have it, let's get the first line (as you showed in your example) from all of the inputs, and concatenate it:

```
my $concatenated = '';

for my $fh ( @fhs ) {
    my $line = <$fh>;
    $concatenated .= $line;
}
```

Which is perfectly fine, and readable, but still can be shortened, while maintaining (in my opinion) readability, to:

```
my $concatenated = join '', map { scalar <$_> } @fhs;
```

Effect is the same - $concatenated contains first lines from all files.

So, whole program would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
# use Fatal qw( open ); # uncomment if you don't have autodie

my @files        = grep { -f } glob( '*.txt' );
my @fhs          = map { open my $fh, '<', $_; $fh } @files;
my $concatenated = join '', map { scalar <$_> } @fhs;
```

Now, it might be that you want to concatenate not just first lines, but all of them. In this situation, instead of `$concatenated = ...` code, you'd need something like this:

```
my $concatenated = '';

while (my $fh = shift @fhs) {
    my $line = <$fh>;
    if ( defined $line ) {
        push @fhs, $fh;
        $concatenated .= $line;
    } else {
        close $fh;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 your code is better than mine. I would love to maintain this kind of code. Although for completeness it might be noted that `glob()` is considered a somewhat unsafe function, and might not work universally. I can't find a reference for that (you might search StackOverflow and see if you can find anything about it - I remember it from a comment, but don't know where to look at this point).

Comment: @Chris: Hmm .. never heard about it, but it's possible. In this case - opendir, readdir + grep, closedir should be sufficient.

Comment: I think that the complaints about `glob` refer to older versions of the function. (It used to use the C-shell?) Nevertheless, here's one Perl coder who doesn't like it and why: http://sial.org/blog/2008/01/many_small_errors.html

Comment: glob, with a fixed string argument, on Perl >= 5.6, is quite safe. The only convincing argument in that blog post is that spaces may cause trouble, but `"*.txt"` is known not to contain spaces. :)

Comment: @Paul - Have you tried reading other comments? Like - mine comment from 3 hours ago: " ... In this case - opendir, readdir + grep, closedir should be sufficient" :)

Comment: @Paul: A few things worth saying for `glob`: (1) no dotfiles (unless you ask for them), (2) order is guaranteed, (3) no need to prepend the directory on the results in order to do filetests.

Answer (score 9):

Here is your problem:

```
for my $i (0..$#files) {
  my @blah = <$files[$i]>;
  $concat .= $blah;
}
```

First, `<$files[$i]>` isn't a valid filehandle read. This is the source of your GLOB(...) errors. See [mobrule's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499672/open-array-of-files-in-perl-simultaneously/1499734#1499734) for why this is the case. So change it to this:

```
for my $file (@files) {
  my @blah = <$file>;
  $concat .= $blah;
}
```

Second problem, You're mixing `@blah` (an array named `blah`) and `$blah` (a scalar named `blah`). This is the source of your "uninitialized value" errors - `$blah` (the scalar) hasn't been initialized, but you're using it. If you want the `$n`-th line from `@blah`, use this:

```
for my $file (@files) {
  my @blah = <$file>;
  $concat .= $blah[$n];
}
```

I don't want to keep beating a dead horse, but I do want to address a better way to do something:

```
my $text = `ls | grep ".txt"`;
my @temps = split(/\n/,$text);
```

This reads in a list of all files in the current directory that have a ".txt" extension in them. This works, and is effective, but it can be rather slow - we have to call out to the shell, which has to fork off to run `ls` and `grep`, and that incurs a bit of overhead. Furthermore, `ls` and `grep` are simple and common programs, but not exactly portable. Surely there's a better way to do this:

```
my @temps;
opendir(DIRHANDLE, ".");
while(my $file = readdir(DIRHANDLE)) {
  push @temps, $file if $file =~ /\.txt/;
}
```

Simple, short, pure Perl, no forking, no non-portable shells, and we don't have to read in the string and *then* split it - we can only store the entries we really need. Plus, it becomes trivial to modify the conditions for files that pass the test. Say we end up accidentally reading the file `test.txt.gz` because our regex matches: we can easily change that line to:

```
  push @temps, $file if $file =~ /\.txt$/;
```

We can do that one with `grep` (I believe), but why settle for `grep`'s limited regular expressions when Perl has one of the most powerful regex libraries anywhere built-in?

Answer (score 1):

Use braces around `$files[$i]` inside the `<>` operator

```
my @blah = <{$files[$i]}>
```

Otherwise Perl interprets `<>` as the file glob operator instead of the read-from-filehandle operator.

Comment: I knew there was a reason `<$files[$i]>` was bad. But that's not the only problem in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some good answers already. Another way to tackle the problem is to create a list-of-lists containing all of the lines from the files (`@content`). Then use the `each_arrayref` function from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils), which will create an iterator that yields line 1 from all files, then line 2, etc.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(each_arrayref);

my @content =
    map {
        open(my $fh, '<', $_) or die $!;
        [<$fh>]
    }
    grep {-f}
    glob '*.txt'
;
my $iterator = each_arrayref @content;
while (my @nth_lines = $iterator->()){
    # Do stuff with @nth_lines;
}
```

Comment: @Brad - It might, but it's a bit cryptic.