# How can I read a directory in Perl with one statement?

Tags: perl, directory

I'm writing a script that looks for certain files in a directory and processes them.  I keep on writing the following:

```
opendir DIR, $dir;
@files = readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;
```

While I *could* (and in fact *should*) wrap this in a function, I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You might want to check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506801/what-reasons-are-there-to-prefer-glob-over-readdir-or-vice-versa-in-perl

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "write a directory"?

Comment: I actually mean "writing the following *code*"

Comment: So could you please edit the title of your question?

Comment: Oh... I forgot that I had written that in the title :)

Comment: Thank you. (can the stupid commment minimum length no longer be tricked?)

Comment: yes, if you add some complaint like you did :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most elegant is to use a function someone else has already written.

```
use File::Slurp;

@files = read_dir $dir;  # . and .. are removed by default
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be to use a [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) block:

```
my @files = do {
    opendir my $d, '/your/dir/';
    readdir $d;
};
```

Its more elegant because *my $d* is local to block (unlike your DIR global) and closedir isn't needed because the filehandle is automatically closed when $d went out of scope.

/I3az/

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [File::Find](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/perl/File/Find.pm.html) for this kind of thing.

Comment: Why would you want to do a depth-first search to get the list of files from one directory?

Answer (score 0):

No one has suggested `glob` yet? OK, here goes:

```
@files = glob("$dir/*");
```

Or if you need files that begin with a dot, too:

```
@files = glob("$dir/{.,}*")
```

Answer (score 0):

glob is the simplest solution.  I do not know what you think the first three lines belong in a subroutine, unless you are opening the files more than once