# How to delete files based on the extension in perl?

Tags: perl, delete-file

I have a problem regarding deletion of files in Perl. I want to delete all files within a folder with the extension `.log`. Is there a smart way to do this in Perl?

I haven't got much experience coding perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fast and dirty: `unlink glob('*.log');`.

I'd recommend manual loop with [`opendir`](http://p3rl.org/opendir)/[`readdir`](http://p3rl.org/readdir) over directory for more control though.

Comment: It works well thx :). But why wouldn't you recommend this way?

Comment: I don't exactly agree in what is "pro" and "con" in this list, but you can see good list of **differences** in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1506801/936986).

Answer (score 0):

I like Oleg's, it's mad short.  I usually hack up something like:

```
$  perl -e 'foreach my $f (@ARGV){ print `ls -l $f`; unlink $f }' *.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 The Genius None 0 Jun 21 06:15 bar.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 The Genius None 0 Jun 21 06:14 foo.log
```

Cause I can't remember all the commands and it's ease to add in tests and regexes.  Also this prints out some indication of what it did. Choose your coffee.